# how to use sql to get number of seconds from a string formatted like "HH:MM:SS"

Tags: sql-server

I have a C# program that recorded a TimeSpan value into a SQL Server table's varchar field.  For example, the varchar field might have the value "00:12:05.7989790".

How could I use SQL code to get that total value in SECONDS?  Since that varchar represents 12 minutes and 5 seconds, I would like a SQL statement that extracts it as "725".

I've tried some code like this:

```
select
   Case when IsDate(the_value)=1 then datepart(HOUR, CONVERT(datetime, the_value))*360 else 0 end
        + Case when IsDate(the_value)=1 then datepart(MINUTE, CONVERT(datetime, the_value))*60 else 0 end
        + Case when IsDate(the_value)=1 then datepart(SECOND, CONVERT(datetime, the_value))*1 else 0 end
from mytable
```

but it complains "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing time in a varchar column? Have you considered using a `time` column? Or storing the start and end as datetime (you can always get the delta)?

Comment: Also, (a) you don't need to repeat the `CASE` expression three times, and (b) try converting to `time(0)` or `datetime2(0)` instead of `datetime` (you have too many decimal places to fit into `datetime`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - if it's a time *span*, I would argue that storing it in a `time` column would be inappropriate. SQL Server doesn't have a decent data type for time spans, and I'd probably argue for an integral type having already converted into a single count of the smallest time element that's relevant (seconds or milliseconds).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I'd prefer two separate datetime or datetime2 columns, but I'll still take time over varchar any day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189794.aspx

DATEDIFF(ss, '00:00:00.000', [your time column])

Answer (score 0):

I would use `datediff()` and use explicit conversion to time:

```
select datediff(second, '00:00:00', convert(time, the_value))
```

If the units can exceed 23 hours, then you have a challenge, because the conversion will fail.  In this case, string manipulation is an option:

```
select (left(the_value, 2) * 60 * 60 + 
        substring(the_value, 3, 2) * 60 + 
        substring(the_value, 5, 2)
       ) as seconds
```

This assumes that all strings are in the proper format.  You can validate this with a `case`:

```
select (case when the_value like '[0-9]0-9]:[0-9[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%'
             then (left(the_value, 2) * 60 * 60 + 
                   substring(the_value, 3, 2) * 60 + 
                   substring(the_value, 5, 2)
                  )
         end) as seconds
```